# Why is my regex not returning any matches?

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

My second regex (the one that feeds into the results variable) isn't returning any matches when there should be one within the data. Why is that?

The dump string is too long to add but can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/h2GPnwYm) and the part I am aiming to find is [here](https://pastebin.com/fnsapK5K)

The code is as follows:

```
#All of this is unimportant
import requests
import re

dump="PASTEBIN TEXT HERE"

x = re.findall(r'href=".*?">',dump)

html = requests.get(x[0].replace("href=","").replace(">","").replace('"',"")).text

#This is the regex we care about; It's done on the html linked in the edit.
results = re.findall(r'<p>Source: <a href.*?</a>',html)

print(results)
```

Edit: [Here](https://pastebin.com/MUcvBQ6K)'s the content of the html string that the results regex is being performed on. My bad.

Edit 2: [Here](https://pastebin.com/Y97sjLpj)'s the full, unedited code that I'm running for people to test.

Comment: Is there a newline between `<a href` and `</a>`? `.` doesn’t match newlines unless you use the `re.DOTALL` flag.

Comment: Did you check the html variable data, where can we see that ?

Comment: Looking at the html code, there isn't any `<p>Source: ...` tag.

Comment: Oh, mystery solved, there are no matches, results is empty !

Comment: @Ry- No newline character. Enabling the flag didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @AndrejKesely There is in the get request. There is data returned from the get request of the url. My bad for not linking it but it can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/MUcvBQ6K)

Comment: Are you expecting multiple urls like https://mediabiasfactcheck.com/act-tv ?

Comment: @QHarr No, the aim is to read the URL (the html content from that has been appended to the OP) and then find the source listed within using the regex. Dump just contains the links that I use to pull the initial post and html contains the html of the article, the issue is that the regex isn't returning the source when it should do.

Comment: @DanHarmon With BeautifulSoup: `BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml').select('p:contains("Source:")')` With `results = re.findall(r'<p>Source: <a href.*?</a>',html)` I get `['<p>Source: <a href="http://act.tv" target="_blank" rel="noopener">http://act.tv</a>']`

Comment: ^^ I did that but I get the url I show

Comment: I think you're looking at the wrong url. What we care about and are doing the regex on is the actual html content of mediabiasfactcheck.com/act-tv

@AndrejKesely Your beautifulsoup code returns the error 'NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.' and running the results code returns an empty list for me.

Comment: ah... my bad then!

Comment: @DanHarmon You should update BeautifulSoup. I use `beautifulsoup4==4.7.1`

Comment: Updated and still got an error ' from bs4.element import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'nonwhitespace_re' from 'bs4.element' (D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py)
]'

Comment: Right, sorry about that answer earlier, I didn't read your comments. I have run the test code you provided and for me, the request didn't contain what you are looking for. However, when I use that response you linked. Your code works, so I'm guessing we're getting the same response.

Comment: @Jojo I dumped the html variable to a file and it's definitely in there. https://pastebin.com/HwPEQr4a

Comment: That's weird, when I dump my html into a file I don't get those elements. Are we requesting the same url? My result when I print the url is: `https://mediabiasfactcheck.com/act-tv/`

Comment: @Jojo Same URL for me too and that link does contain the data we're searching for if you go check it out and view the html.

Comment: I think you have a typo in ur regex string, try this: `results = re.findall(r'<a href.*?<\/a>',html)`

Comment: Seems like there is only one match [\(<p\s*>\s*Source\s*:\s*<a\s+href\[\S\s\]*?</a\s*>\)](https://regex101.com/r/btCDku/1)

Comment: I mean you could get fancy and do this thing that insures a better outcome, but, its up to you. `(<p\s*>\s*Source\s*:\s*<a(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\shref\s*=\s*(?:(['"])(?:(?!\2)[\S\s])*\2))\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]?)+>[\S\s]*?</a\s*>)`

Comment: That's the exact result I want, I only get None returned though... did you get that from running my code? Could it be to do with using the anaconda implementation and should I try on cpython

@JCHernández that doesn't find the specific source I'm after, we need the link href between the p tag with 'Source:' and the closing a tag. That just matches every href.